# how can I see the aspx.vb and aspx.designer.vb under my aspx file?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

On this project you can see aspx.designer.vb  and aspx.vb under the aspx file

[image]

but on my project I don't have it?? ,, what gives??

I can view the vb code by right click then click view code.

How can I make the aspx.vb and the designer file to show under the aspx file?

[image]

thankx

One more picture. I can see the designer file and VB file in file explorer

[image]

Comment: Are the designer and code behind files actually there and not included in the project? Or were they not included/generated and you want to have them generated?

Comment: Did you not specify separate file for code and markup? Is your code in the aspx file?

Comment: I can see the designer and the vb file under file explorer. so I think I don't need to generate them is that correct?  I just need them to show up in visual studio solution explorer

Answer (score 7, accepted):

just press Show All Files on Solution Expolorer ToolBar

Answer (score 0):

It Could be beacause:

1) You need to press the button  (top of the explore panel)

> Nested related file

2) The file is created with the code in the same aspx file. When you create a new aspx file you could check de option

> place code in a separate file

3) For some reason your codebehind isn't included in the project. If this is the case include it.